# pull and back start position RelativeLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-animation

How to implement the following mechanism (see image http://goo.gl/acy5D):

1. Pull down RelativeLayout
2. RelativeLayout animation back to start position

similar mechanisms:
(see image http://goo.gl/AIKdn)

Path app

Google+ app

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Sliding Drawer widget? I think making a custom one would suffice your requirement.